# Why (root as MovieClip).this["mc"+i] doesnt work?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

How can I control 3 movie clips from another mc dynamically?
My 3 clips are mc1, mc2 and mc3. What is wrong with the codes given below?

```
for(i=1;i<=3;i++){
(root as MovieClip).this["mc"+i];
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you should have used central code. That means all code in one place telling all MCs what to do. Logic of code would be `IF otherMC.clicked == true THEN { mc1 = do  function1, mc2 = do  function2... etc..} ELSE { do something}`. Are you using timeline? Put all code in a layer on frame 1, then add another layer + (still on frame 1) add a movieClip to be container (like Stage). Now your code controls all MCs added to container without errors, your code also holds all functions (not inside movieclips) so everything is controlled from frame 1 centrally...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Child is not a property of his parent, you can use `(root as MovieClip).get ChildByName('mc'+i)`.

Comment: Thank suzuiyue. But I get an error when I try to call a function.
for(i=1;i<=3;i++){
(root as MovieClip).getChildByName.functionName();
}
Error message is: 
1061: Call to a possibly undefined method functionName through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject.

Comment: what's `functionName()`? is it a method of `MovieClip`?